# c# mvc html editorfor default dynamic value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]This is my controller C# code.

```
var timeList = new List<string>
{
    "8.00 AM",
    "8.15 AM",
    "8.30 AM",
    "8.45 AM",
    "9.00 AM",
    "9.15 AM",
    "9.30 AM"
    "17.00 PM"
};
ViewBag.TimeList = timeList;
```

Are there anyways to modify my above code start time from 8.00 to 17.00 with 15 mints interval with display my timeList?

This is my View model

```
@foreach (var T1 in ViewBag.TimeList)
{
    @T1
}
```

I have already added my code `@Value = @T1` but it is not working

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control myPicker", @Value = @T1 } })
    <br />
    <span id="mySpan-@i"></span>
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how do I automatically fill out web forms time with interval (eg, 8.00, 8.15..etc) when page first loading.

Comment: Unclear what your wanting to do. `@Value = @T1` cannot work since `T1` does not exist in the context of the loop (and in any case you should NEVER attempt to set the `value` attribute when using a HtmlHelper). What is the reason to the `@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` loop?

Comment: I am sorry, I have already removed @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) loop. It is not necessary.

Comment: You still have a `@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` loop for creating 3 identical inputs. Your code does not make any sense so its a bit hard to understand what you want the output of that loop to be. And what is the type of property `Time`?

Comment: I am using  model IList, my C# code var timeList = new List<string> time string  and Time property is string because I need only time valve.

Comment: So are you wanting to display a list box to select times? And what is the `for` loop for? You need to explain what you want the output to be (by editing your question).

Comment: Form wiill genetare auto model IList, for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++). After page load, auto generated Time field first text box value will display 8.00am next box 8.15am etc.. For my above example i value max 3, it'll generate 3 Textbox and should display first textbox default valve 8.00am, next 8.15am and 8.30am

Comment: So what does `ViewBag.TimeList` have to do with it? You need to set the value of `model.Time` to the collection and then use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Time[i], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control myPicker" })` in the `for` loop.

Comment: I am going to use time ViewBag.TimeList  and insert value to DB table field Time also I set up property for TIme

Comment: Sorry, but your not making any sense (and your code certainly does not). Unless you edit your question to explain exactly what your out put should be - and perhaps an image might help) then you may as well delete the question

Comment: I have already added image, what I need first time page load display exactly (I have 3 text box) display time 8.00am, 8.15am and 8.30am. That all

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly (you don't need the `ViewBag` property - you need to set the property of your model).

Comment: Thanks I am okay with set the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear what the purpose of the `ViewBag.TimeList` property is, but in order to display your textboxes, you need to set the value of the `Time` property of your model.

In the GET method

```
model.Time = new List<string>(){ "8.00 AM", "8.15 AM", "8.30 AM" }); // set the initial default values
....
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Time.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Time[i], new { @class = "form-control myPicker" })
}
```

Comment: I used ViewBag.TimeList  because I have GET method return another value. Are there anyway to add multiple return value example return View(DataList, model);

Comment: Not clear what your asking. You need to ask a new question which the relevant code - I have already answered this one :)

Comment: Pleasure, but your already have one downvote and I almost did the same. Next time you ask a question, explain (1) what your trying to achieve (2) the relevant code (which in this case should have included what the `Time` property is since you use it in the view) and (3) what is actually happening.